# Angle between a vector and its image

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that $A:X \to GL(d, \mathbb{R})$ be a continuous function on a compact metric space $X$. Assume that there is a compact set $Y\subset X$ such that for any non-zero $u \in \mathbb{R}^d$, we have $V_{u, Y}:=\operatorname{span}\{ A(x)u: x\in Y \}=\mathbb{R}^d$.

Is it true that there is $x \in Y$ such that for all non zero vector $u$, the angle between $A(x)u$ and $u$ is bounded from below?

Comment: I don't understand the question; all angles are bounded. Do you mean bounded independent of $d$ or something else? Which objects in this question are being fixed and which are varying?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I meant the angular distance by the angle. I mean bounded independent of vectors. $Y$ is fixed and a vector $u$ is varying. Please let me know if you have more questions

Comment: What is "angular distance" if it isn't a synonym for "angle"? Can you write down a precise question with all quantifiers explicit and a precise definition of "angle" or "angular distance"?

Comment: angle between nonzero vectors, we mean the angle between the lines spanned by the vectors..

Comment: Okay, that number is always at most $\pi$. So *what is your question*??? Please write down a precise definition of "bounded."

Comment: I modified the questions. Please let me know if there is any problems.

Comment: The question looks the same to me; in particular I still don't understand what you mean by "bounded." Why isn't "yes, it's always bounded, by $\pi$" an answer to your question?

Comment: Bounded means: there is $\delta>0$ such that for every non-zero vectors $u, v$, the angle $\angle (v, u) >\delta.$

Comment: You mean bounded *below* then? That would have been very useful to clarify earlier!

Comment: I meant bounded from the below

Comment: In that case I still don't understand your question; I think you want the bound $\delta$ to be independent of something you haven't made explicit. As written, it seems to me that a matrix $M$ satisfies the first property iff $\pm 1$ isn't an eigenvalue, and it never satisfies the second property because we can always take $v = A(x) u$. So I still don't think I understand what you mean. *Please* write down an explicit question *with all quantifiers*.

Comment: I want to prove that there is $\delta>0$ such that there is $x \in Y$ such that for all non zero vector $v$, the angle between $A(x)v$ and $v$ is bounded from the below by $\delta.$

Comment: Okay, in that case Chris's answer is a correct counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A(Y)$ be the set of matrices $M$ with the following properties:

- $M$ has exactly two eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$;
- Every entry of $M$ is in the interval $[-2,2]$.

Then, for each $M\in A(Y)$ you will have a $0$-degree angle and a $180$-degree angle somewhere.

Comment: Why the span is $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Adam even by guessing, you can see that there are so many matrices in $A(Y)$, the span has to be $\mathbb{R}^2$. To see this formally, just look at the $2$-by-$2$ matrices where one of the diagonal entries is $1$, the other diagonal entry is $-1$, and the remaining entries are $0,\pm1$. Imagine you are applying all these matrices to the vector $(a,b)$.